# Invalid input data. Please verify unique constraints Strapi

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, strapi

I'm trying to add a product data in my Strapi product, but sometimes it shows "Invalid input data. Please verify unique constraints" errors. Anyone have dealt with this before?

I got `{statusCode: 400, error: "Bad Request", message: "Invalid input data. Please verify unique constraints"}` in my console.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me due to mismatch in package versions. The ultimate solution that worked for me was to upgrade the package to 3.5.x.

More details here: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/9369

Comment: Hello, my version right now is 3.5.0, so I should just upgrade?

Comment: Yes, go ahead and update it to the latest version. That would probably fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I was missing `const axios = require('axios');` in some of my model files. I did webhooks myself for each model using axios to send a POST request.

Try `npm run strapi console` It was very helpful. It did show an erorr in a console with enough info, as I tried to update a field in a single type.

Maybe you missing something in your model/service/controller. Strapi console will reveal it, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in the context of lifecycle hooks, I got this error while trying to do one in v3.

My mistake was not adding another parameter to the beforeUpdate method

```
Before : 
async beforeUpdate(data) {
  console.log(data);
  data.ImageUrlTest = "testurlimage";
},


After:
async beforeUpdate(params, data) {
  console.log(params);
  data.ImageUrlTest = "testurlimage";
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue today. The "Invalid input data. Please verify unique constraints" displayed on the frontend seems to be a catch-all message and isn't always indicative of a unique constraint issue.

In my case, it was because the value I was trying to enter in a particular field was longer than the fields max length.
We had the data type `Short text` selected for the field, but the particular value I was trying to save when the error occurred was 283 chars long.

You might find your issue to be a similar DB error being masked by the generic error message as well.

I was able to find this error by reading the Strapi server logs - this revealed the actual error message `value too long for type character varying(255)`

```
1|strapi-dev  | [2023-02-22T19:07:19.844Z] error error: insert into "components_resources_content_resource_sections" ("sectionBodyRichText", "sectionVideoUrl") values ($1, $2) returning * - value too long for type character varying(255)
1|strapi-dev  |     at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
1|strapi-dev  |     at Parser.handlePacket (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
1|strapi-dev  |     at Parser.parse (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
1|strapi-dev  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:10:42)
1|strapi-dev  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
1|strapi-dev  |     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:486:12)
1|strapi-dev  |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
1|strapi-dev  |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
1|strapi-dev  |     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
1|strapi-dev  |     at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
1|strapi-dev  | From previous event:
1|strapi-dev  |     at Child.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/model.js:1160:42)
1|strapi-dev  | From previous event:
1|strapi-dev  |     at Child.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/model.js:1159:14)
1|strapi-dev  |     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
1|strapi-dev  | From previous event:
1|strapi-dev  |     at Child.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/model.js:1060:10)
1|strapi-dev  | From previous event:
1|strapi-dev  |     at runCreate (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/strapi-connector-bookshelf/lib/queries.js:113:45)
1|strapi-dev  |     at wrapTransaction (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/strapi-connector-bookshelf/lib/queries.js:52:29)
1|strapi-dev  |     at create (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/strapi-connector-bookshelf/lib/queries.js:120:12)
1|strapi-dev  |     at Object.create (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/strapi-connector-bookshelf/lib/queries.js:58:20)
1|strapi-dev  |     at fn (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/strapi-database/lib/queries/helpers.js:31:54)
1|strapi-dev  |     at Object.create (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/strapi-database/lib/queries/helpers.js:15:24)
1|strapi-dev  |     at async Promise.all (index 0)
1|strapi-dev  |     at async updateComponents (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/strapi-connector-bookshelf/lib/queries.js:408:13)
1|strapi-dev  |     at async runUpdate (/home/ec2-user/content-creation-service/app/node_modules/strapi-connector-bookshelf/lib/queries.js:146:7)
```